# Creating DataRelation with Parent and Child tables and generating xml with subnodes for child table

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim obj_DataTable As New System.Data.DataTable("Category")
    Dim obj_DataSet As New DataSet()
    'Declaring the array of DataColum to hold the Primary Key Columns
    Dim obj_PrimaryClmn(1) As System.Data.DataColumn
    Dim obj_DataRow As System.Data.DataRow
    Dim obj_DataRelation As DataRelation
    Dim writer As New System.IO.StringWriter

    obj_DataTable.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("CategoryId"))
    obj_DataTable.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("CategoryName"))

    obj_PrimaryClmn(0) = obj_DataTable.Columns(0)
    'Assigning the CategoryId column as Primary Key
    obj_DataTable.PrimaryKey = obj_PrimaryClmn

    'Entering the data in Category Table
    obj_DataRow = obj_DataTable.NewRow()
    obj_DataRow.Item(0) = 0
    obj_DataRow.Item(1) = "Select Category"
    obj_DataTable.Rows.Add(obj_DataRow)

    obj_DataRow = obj_DataTable.NewRow()
    obj_DataRow.Item(0) = 1
    obj_DataRow.Item(1) = "Computers"
    obj_DataTable.Rows.Add(obj_DataRow)

    obj_DataSet.Tables.Add(obj_DataTable)

    obj_DataTable.PrimaryKey = obj_PrimaryClmn

    Dim obj_DataRow1 As System.Data.DataRow
    Dim obj_DataTable1 As New System.Data.DataTable("Product")

    obj_DataTable1.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("ProductId"))
    obj_DataTable1.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("ProductName"))
    obj_DataTable1.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("CategoryId"))

    obj_DataRow1 = obj_DataTable1.NewRow()
    obj_DataRow1.Item(0) = 1
    obj_DataRow1.Item(1) = "PHP"
    obj_DataRow1.Item(2) = 1
    obj_DataTable1.Rows.Add(obj_DataRow1)

    obj_DataSet.Tables.Add(obj_DataTable1)

    Dim obj_ParentClmn, obj_ChildClmn As DataColumn

    obj_ParentClmn = obj_DataSet.Tables("Category").Columns("CategoryId")
    obj_ChildClmn = obj_DataSet.Tables("Product").Columns("CategoryId")

    obj_DataRelation = New DataRelation("relation_Category_Product", obj_ParentClmn, obj_ChildClmn)

    obj_DataSet.Relations.Add(obj_DataRelation)

    obj_DataSet.WriteXml(writer)

    MsgBox(writer.ToString())
```

This code executes. There is a relation between parent and child tables. This code first displays xml from first and xml from the second table one after the other. I don't need this way. Because relation is there the xml should display first table in xml and its second table as a child node of first table. How can it be possible? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Relation Type to `Nested` as per below code, it will populate child table as subnodes in XML.

```
obj_DataRelation = New DataRelation("relation_Category_Product", obj_ParentClmn, obj_ChildClmn)
obj_DataRelation.Nested = True
obj_DataSet.Relations.Add(obj_DataRelation)
```

[Refer here to know more about nesting of nodes, great knowledge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk6y3s8y.aspx)

Comment: This solution works fine for parent and child tables with primary key and foreign key relationship. But is it possible to have another table completely different table with multiple rows to act as nested child node.

Comment: Please accept this answer because it satisfies your question and post a new question with the scenario.